# How does RabbitMQ handle multiple producers trying to write to the queue at the same time?

Tags: rabbitmq

Let's say I have 10 busy producers who are constantly trying to write to a single RabbitMQ queue.

How does RabbitMQ handle all these concurrent connections? Does it make each connection wait before accepting their data and adding it to the queue?

Does it use a round robin method or some other way?

Does increasing the number of cores on the RabbitMQ server improve how many connections it can handle, or is having multiple cores pointless as there's only one queue?

Basically I'm trying to figure out the ideal RabbitMQ server setup to ensure it can handle my hypothetical 10 busy producer + 1 queue scenario.

Thanks.

Comment: I doubt that 10 concurrent connections will cause any modern queue broker to break a sweat. Worry about it when you have hundreds, or when you notice a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Does that mean a server with 2GB RAM and 2 cores could handle this sort of load, or is that way underpowered?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "busy", on the size of the messages, how long you expect to keep going if the consumers pause, etc.  Benchmark it yourself. Use an Amazon EC2 instance if the obstacle is buying hardware.

Comment: ... but in "normal" operation where it's only a few hundred messages/second, each of <2KB, with the consumer taking as fast as the messages arrive, I would hope a Raspberry Pi would keep up!